# How to split word from CString?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, atl, cstring

I have a 
first case:
`CString stVal = " dsc | resource.c |* ";`

in Second case:

```
CString stVal = " resource.c |MS";
```

I want only file name in both case.

Please note that I am using visual studio 6.0.

have you any idea?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried `CString::Tokenize`?

Comment: I am using vs 6.0. Tokenize is not supported ...

Comment: Use CString::Find to find the position of the "." or ".c". Then step back until a non-alphanumeric character to find the beginning of the file name. Then use CString::Mid to extract.

Answer (score 1):

CString strLine= " dsc | resource.c |* ";

```
    char* lpszToToken = stLine.GetBuffer(stLine.GetLength());
    char* lpszToken = strtok(lpszToToken, "|");
    while(lpszToken != NULL)
    {
        lpszToken = strtok(NULL, "|");
        CString str = lpszToken;
        if(str.Find(".") != -1) {
            stLine = str;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

recently doing MFC experiment meeting the same problem, finnaly sovled by following code.

```
split(CString A) {
    CStringList* returnStringList = new CStringList;
    CString Seperator = L"|";//custom your serperator here
    int position = 0;
    CString token = A.Tokenize(Seperator, position);
    returnStringList->AddTail(token);
    while (!token.IsEmpty()) {
        token = A.Tokenize(Seperator, position);
        returnStringList->AddTail(token);
    }
    return returnStringList;
}
```